# Selecting a specific BottomNavigationBar when routing from another widget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Please, help.  This is my first project using Flutter.  I am making an app for pets.

I have Homepage widget that has 4 bottom Navbar (Home, Photos, Medical, Profile).  In Profile I have a button "About", which opens a widget about us.

But when I am trying to return to back from About, it returns to "Home" NavBottombar. I am trying to select Profile NavBottomBar.
I think that is related to current index in Homepage, which equals 0 at the beginning.  But how can I change from 0 to 2 while routing?

homepage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'placeholder_widget.dart';
import 'dashboard.dart';
import 'medical.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
import 'about.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Homepage(),
    ));

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<Homepage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Dashboard(),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.deepOrange),
    PlaceholderWidget(Colors.red),
    // Medical(),
    Profile()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Furball Tales'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent[400],
        ),
        body: _children[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.perm_media),
              title: Text('Photos'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.local_hospital),
              title: Text('Medical'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
              title: Text('Profile'),
            ),
          ],
          selectedItemColor: Colors.cyanAccent[400],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

about.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'profile.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

class About extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('About FurBallTales'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent[400],
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return Homepage();
              }), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
            )),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 30,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Text(
                    'OUR MISSION',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.tealAccent[400]),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 25,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Text(
                    'Strengthening the bond of owners and pets, more than ever',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[500],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[100],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

profile.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sign_in.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';
import 'about.dart';
import 'donation.dart';

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 80,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSxDoD5caxFUy_dn0w6wl01m882CeJHNVOCRg&usqp=CAU'),
              ),
              Text(
                '<$name>',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '<$email>',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
                  color: Colors.red[400],
                  letterSpacing: 2.5,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
                width: 200,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.teal[200],
                ),
              ),
              //   this is about page-----------------------------------------
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return About();
                  }), ModalRoute.withName('/about'));
                },
                child: Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 25.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.help,
                        color: Colors.teal[900],
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        'About',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'BalooBhai', fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return Donation();
                  }), ModalRoute.withName('/about'));
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.monetization_on,
                      color: Colors.teal[900],
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'Donation',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Neucha'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  signOutGoogle();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return LoginPage();
                  }), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.account_circle,
                      color: Colors.teal[900],
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      'LOGOUT',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontFamily: 'Neucha'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where you have : onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return Homepage();
              }), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
            },     use Navigator.pop();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `pushAndRemoveUntil` in your `About` page, you can use `Navigator.pop(context)`( which removes the view from the `Navigator stack`):

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```dart
class About extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('About FurBallTales'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent[400],
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
             Navigator.pop(context); // pop the view 
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
            )),
      ),
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

---

NOTE:

With this approach, the state of the `BottomNavigationBar` is reserved.

Comment: When I used  Navigator.pop(context),  it returns black screen.

Comment: How are you navigating to the `Profile Page` ? Can you navigate like `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> About()))` ? @Mukha

Comment: Thank you, it worked.    First I did push context,  then used pop context.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says `return Homepage();` in `about.dart` you could change that to return the profile widget.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  When I returned directly to Profile, I lost all NavBottomBar.

Comment: Maybe adding the Navbottombar to the profile code will make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone, who helped me.

The problem has been solved this way:

First, I pushed to new page.

```
 onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => About()));
                  
                }
```

Then made pop context.

```
 onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            
            },
```

It returned initial position.